# I have to update my database password and mysql start command is not working

Tags: mysql, passwords, putty

I have to reset my MySQL password but I am unable to start MySQL service using PuTTY.
Whenever I try to start the service it says fail.

Comment: How are you starting it? Can you start mysqld in interactive mode and see what it outputs? Or see in your mysql.err or mysql.log if there are any errors?

Comment: I am using sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop command to start

Comment: Check your mysql.log and mysql.err to see what does it say. Or run mysqld manually or mysqld_safe and see if you get any errors.

Comment: 140326 07:31:12 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140326 08:37:25 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140326  8:37:25 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140326  8:37:25 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.

Comment: 140326  8:37:25 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140326  8:37:25 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140326  8:37:25 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140326  8:37:25 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140326  8:37:25 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140326  8:37:25 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140326  8:37:25 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140326  8:37:25 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool

Comment: There you go. Fatal error, not enough memory. I suggest you start from there.

Comment: How much memory does your server have? How much memory is free? What is the biggest memory hog? What is your current innodb_buffer_pool_size in my.cnf? I suggest you open a separate question with this information, and continue there.

Comment: Thanks the issue was size of server,it helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

***I've to update my database password and mysql start command is not working:***

```
SET PASSWORD [FOR user] =
    {
        PASSWORD('cleartext password')
      | OLD_PASSWORD('cleartext password')
      | 'encrypted password'
    }
```

***refer this links:***

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html***

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/default-privileges.html***

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html***

**https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html**